# При Unity билде выходит ошибка - Duplicate class kotlin

Tags: android, unity3d, android-studio, kotlin

При Unity билде выходит ошибка **Duplicate class kotlin**

Я ещё не разбираюсь в настройке подобных Android файлов через Gradle и Manifest, но я в поисках информации про данную ошибку при билде Unity, понял что необходимо в gradle выбрать одну из этих дубликатов или исключить одну из них.

```
Duplicate class kotlin ... -1.3.50.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin ... -1.3.50.jar) and org.jetbrains.kotlin ... -1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin ... -1.3.72.jar)
```

Просьба подсказать что мне следует сделать конкретно? Где найти необходимые файлы, необходимые места куда что написать, в сети я не нашёл подобной информации только поверхностные ответы по типу пропиши в Gradle.bundle impliment какую нибудь версию.

Очень нужна помощь специалиста кто сможешь обьяснить где это находится. Не могу никак собрать проект и найти ответ на данный вопрос, я в тупике

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найдено решение:

Суть ошибки в том что в проекте по собственным причинам был создан дубликат класса и движок при сборке не смог определить какой класс необходимо использовать

Необходимо в Main Gradle Template файле вашего проект вставить следующий код в **dependencies** блоке:

```
 implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin:1.3.50)
```

Чтобы включить этот файл который не доступен изначально необходимо зайти в **Project Settings -> Player и в Publishing Settings** активировать **Custom Main Gradle Template** после появится путь к файлу который нужно будет открыть

[image: Custom Main Gradle Template]